# Laravel Queue Worker, RabbitMQ and running jobs generated remotely

Tags: php, laravel, rabbitmq

I'll preface this by admitting slight sleep-deprivation.

The setup is as follows:

**API Endpoint (Server A)** receives an incoming call, and adds this to a specific queue on the RabbitMQ Server (Server B).

**RabbitMQ (Server B)** is simply a RabbitMQ Queue Server. Nothing more, nothing less.

**Laravel Installation (Server C)** is our actual Laravel install, which is meant to look for jobs on specific queues and do things with them.

We have a RabbitMQ package in the Laravel install, which allows the use of the regular Laravel Queue mechanics over a RabbitMQ connection.

The issue I've come across is that we can spawn a worker for a queue - but since we're not generating the jobs passing a `$job` class (the job content itself is most often a JSON array), the Laravel install has no idea what to do with the job.

So my question revolves mainly around how to approach a scenario like this. I'm thinking that using the Queue-functionality in Laravel won't do what I need it to do. Can you see an approach that I'm missing? Do I really need to spawn a daemon on a non-framework script to handle this?

Your input is much appreciated!

Comment: Is there no way that you look into json array and make sense of what the job is or can be then prepare it in laravel to do that?

Comment: @FarrukhSubhani The issue is that the queue worker in Laravel runs a job based on the specified $job (a script), which is sort of reversed to how I need this to function since the $job won't be available from the server creating the job to begin with.

Comment: Thinking about this further, perhaps the best option is to have Server A also run a simpler Laravel installation with a copy of the same job. It would then be able to dispatch that job, and since an equal copy exists on the server running it, it should function. Not a fan of that idea though as it overcomplicates my design - so if anyone has a better idea, I'm all ears!

Comment: laravel's jobs implementation assume the same codebase on producer and consumer, as it contains serialised classes to provide higher level of abstraction. If you are happy to wipe out the queue each release, you can do that. Alternatively you can implement consumers on the lower level listening to the raw messages and routing them according to content of the message. A bit more work, yet much more flexibility.

Comment: As said above, in order to let laravel handle the job/payload properly, your publishing code  have to generate same message as laravel publisher will do. The laziest way to do that is to get one message generated by laravel and generate your own following the same pattern. You would normally need to alter class name and payload (json string, afair).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is indeed to replicate the job code onto the one issuing the job. The code will not need every dependency that the job requires to actually function, as it only serializes the job from the one pushing it.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach would be a listener on your Laravel application consuming the JSON messages an acting on those.

A queue listener can be created using a package such as https://github.com/bschmitt/laravel-amqp (a generic AMQP bridge for Laravel) or https://github.com/needle-project/laravel-rabbitmq (a bridge more specialised for RabbitMQ).

The queue consumer then reads the JSON payload, saves the paymload as appropriate data, then decides what jobs to dispatch as a result within the Laravel application, as handled by the https://github.com/vyuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq package.

The the two applications still communicate with plain JSON, and not the Laravel-oriented JSON containing the serialised job class.